# How to connect two interactions so that the select menu appears after pressing the button discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

How to connect two interactions so that the select menu appears after pressing the button discord.py....?
I searched in all the documentation, but I didn't find anything similar..
I don't deny that I'm stupid, but please help

Answer (score -2):

To connect two interactions in Discord.py, you'll need to use the `discord_components` library. This library allows you to create interactive components such as buttons, select menus, and more. To make the select menu appear after pressing the button, you can follow these steps:

1. Install the required libraries:

Make sure you have `discord.py` and `discord_components` installed. You can install them using pip:

```bash
pip install discord.py
pip install discord-components
```

2. Import necessary modules:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, Select, SelectOption
```

3. Create the bot instance and set up the client:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

4. Add an event listener for the `on_ready` event and initialize `DiscordComponents`:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")
    DiscordComponents(bot)
```

5. Create a command or event that triggers the button and select menu:

```py
@bot.command()
async def show_button_with_select(ctx):
    # Send a message with the button and mention how to use it
    message = await ctx.send("Press the button to see the select menu!", components=[Button(label="Show Select Menu", custom_id="show_select")])

    # Wait for the button click event
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.custom_id == "show_select" and i.message == message)

    # Respond to the button click
    await interaction.respond(content="Select your option:", components=[
        Select(placeholder="Choose an option...", options=[
            SelectOption(label="Option 1", value="option_1"),
            SelectOption(label="Option 2", value="option_2"),
            SelectOption(label="Option 3", value="option_3")
        ], custom_id="select_menu")
    ])
```

6. Run the bot:

```py
bot.run("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")
```

Now, when you use the `!show_button_with_select` command, it will send a message with a button. After you click the button, it will display the select menu with three options: "Option 1", "Option 2", and "Option 3". You can choose one of these options from the select menu.

Keep in mind that this code assumes you have already set up your Discord bot token. Replace `"YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"` with your actual bot token in the `bot.run()` line. Additionally, ensure that you've enabled the necessary intents for your bot in the Discord Developer Portal, specifically the `message_content` intent for this example to work correctly.

Comment: Why are you using `discord-components` rather than the built-in `ui` module in discord.py? What are the advantages?

Comment: Unfortunately Discord components was needed for for the library discord.py prior to version 2.0
, its development was discontinued and it is not supported by python 3.10 :c but thanx anyway

Comment: This is clearly a ChatGPT answer, the first and final paragraphs are dead giveaways. Discord.py resumed development over a year ago and supports 3.10. You don't need janky third-party libraries, these just break your dpy installation.

Comment: this is the chatgpt answer